# Related rate problem involving volume of cone.

Tags: calculus

1. Gravel is being dumped from a conveyor belt at a rate of 30 $ft^3$/min, and its coarseness is such that it forms a pile in the shape of a cone whose base diameter and height are always equal. How fast is the height of the pile increasing when the pile is 10 ft high?

Here is my solution. Is this right?

So we're given:

- b = h. So 2r = h so r = $\frac{h}{2}$
- $\frac{dv}{dt} = 30 \frac{ft^3}{min}$
- $h = 10$

So let's related volume of the cone to the givens:

$$V = \pi \cdot r^2 \frac{h}{3}$$

$$V = \pi \cdot (\frac{h}{2})^2 \frac{h}{3}$$
$$ = \pi \frac{h^3}{12}$$
$$V' = \frac{\pi}{12} \cdot h^3 = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$

$$ \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt} \cdot \frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{h^2}$$
$$= 30 \frac{ft^3}{min} \cdot \frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{100 ft^2} = 0.3819 \frac{ft}{min}$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I sometimes have trouble handling units per measures. Is this normal?

Comment: What do you mean? The unit of measurement of the answer?

Comment: Like its hard to keep track of the units. Any advice on this front?

Comment: Just always write out your units. If you do, they will allow for cancellation giving you units for the final answer.